# how to remove the last 2 layers within a vgg16 pre-trained model

Tags: deep-learning, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I'm trying to figure out how get keep delete certain layers in order to get a model up to `block3_pool` (MaxPooling2D).

```
IMAGE_SIZE = [32, 32]
model = VGG16(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False, classes=10)
```

I tried `model.layers = model.layers[:-3]` and it did not work, also `model._layers.pop()` is not effecting the model output.

Answer (score 0):

```
layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model_vgg.layers])
outputa = layer_dict['block3_pool'].output
new_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model_vgg.input, outputs=outputa)
```